# How to detect your app disconnected when other app streaming display for chrome cast & iOS App

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, chromecast

Currently i'm developing an iOS App with Chrome Cast feature. My question is How to detect with code when the app already streaming display & other app change the display? Currently,my app still show it still connected with the chrome cast but reality is not.

One more question,what is the code for reconnect to chrome cast?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand the question; if you mean how to detect that your app got disconnected because another app started casting to the same device, then it can be achieved by registering a callback to be notified when your connection to the cast device is lost. If you were asking a different question, please clarify.

Comment: yes! you get my question.what callback do i need to register?

Comment: Look at GCKDeviceManagerDelegate in the iOS SDK Apis. In general, it is a good idea if you read the documentation and look at the sample projects.